# MVVM Light Views - Page vs UserControl

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

Can somebody help me understand what the real difference is and why the MVVM Light toolkit users UserControl's for Views instead of Pages?  I know there are some inherient differences between UserControl's and pages like access to the "NavigationService" on a page.

And some of the examples from John Papa's implementation of the MVVM Light use Page instead UserControl, but if you use the MVVM Light "View" Template it uses a UserControl.

thanks

dbl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Page` within a Silverlight application is designed to be hosted within a `Frame` - and is part of the navigation framework (see the MSDN [Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) documentation). Applications of this style navigate from page to page, with the URL updating to reflect the current location, in much the same way as HTML-based websites.

A `UserControl`, is a re-useable unit of your user-interface. It is typically composed of a number of controls, UI elements - and may have some code-behind to perform logic.

If MVVM Light used Pages instead of UserControls, the framework would only be useful for navigation-based Silverlight applications, which are not terribly popular. However, UserControls can be hosted inside any other Panel or Page, therefore this approach is more flexible. A `UserControl` can be used as the content of a `Page`, but can also be used in many other contexts.